# Firebase - retrieving data from a date

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data from a particular date from `Firebase`. They are stored in the following format:

[image]

I am using a `datePicker` to choose a date. But I am not able to figure out how I can change the date chosen to the above format.

**For example:** I choose a date say `28th March 2018`. I would use the code:

```
int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
String month = datePicker.getMonth() + "";
String year = datePicker.getYear() + "";
```

But I am not able to figure out how to change it to the following format, `Wed Mar 28 2018 00:00:00 GMT+530 (IST)`

Comment: a best practice is to store in your database the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390629/how-can-i-sort-data-by-field-stored-string-as-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss/49391814#49391814

Comment: I agree with Renaud, you have to store time in the form of milliseconds, then the any conversion will be possible.

Comment: Actually, since you're storing a *date* and not a timestamp, you can also consider storing them date in a more readable format such as `2018-12-01`.

Comment: I am getting the date from Google Spreadsheet which is automatically converting the date to this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending hours, trying to figure out a way, I have finally found a solution and have realized that this was a pretty silly question to ask. Nevertheless, this is what I have come up with,

```
int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
int year = datePicker.getYear();
int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;

try {
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy");
     Date date = sdf.parse(day + "-" + month + "-" + year);

     sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy");
     String strDate = sdf.format(date) + " 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)";

     Log.d("date_simple", strDate);

} catch (ParseException e) {
     Log.d("date_simple", e + "");
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```